# Can we watch the light travelling in slow motion?

Tags: speed-of-light

If light travels 3 lac km in 1 second we cannot see it moving and it seems to be continuous. Everything in our lives are far slower than this.

Like we cannot differentiate between the different images that make a movie clip if it changes 60 frames a second and the movie is continuous. Of course, as each frame or image making a movie clip has its own identity we can differentiate between each one of them while we cannot differentiate between light it is continuous.

i have read somewhere recently a scientist in UK has succeeded to slow down the light by moving it between certain molecules at specific temperatures and pressure.

If we make a movie of light and try to watch it in slow motion. How much slow moving it may seem? can i slow it to more than 60 times per second.

Do we have a instrument which can help us watch the light in slow motion. about 1/300 000 000 times slower so that in each fraction of time in seconds it only moves 1 meter. And since I want to make it seem to move in slow motion I will be able to watch it over a longer period of time. obviously I cannot watch what happens in that small fraction of second.

Comment: Yes, watch [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qdKEYw-HHAE) video

Comment: I've timed electrons, using stroboscopic techniques, at subpicosecond time scales; others have done it at subfemtosecond time scales. These are stop motion techniques, a million million frames per second and faster. And yet, each frame catches different things happening. There is no indication that motion is discontinuous at these time scales.

Comment: @TheGhostOfPerdition @ Peter-Diehr I watched the video and notice the light still seems continuous just seems to move slow in the movie.

Comment: Hi dear Peter, are you using attosecond laser for such purposes? It is a very new frontier that I hope someday will nail down the kinematics of electrons revolving the nucleus in this case.

Comment: @TheGhostOfPerditio do we also need a zoom i.e resize the image of light/ photons to have a more clearer picture in addition to watching it in slow motion? Not sure about a radii or size of photon when treated as a particle. i.e is zoomed slowmotion video ?

Comment: @Peter-Diehr  is it possible zoomed slowmotion video? Please check my other  comment above.

Comment: My colleagues generated attosecond pulses; I was generating 200 femtosecond electron pulses. Another colleague created stationary optical fields in nanoparticles - evanescent fields which are trapped, but the phases changed continuously at the time scales monitored.

Comment: @Peter-Diehr Were you trying to find the largest amount of time in which light seemed to be still and not moving ?

Comment: No; I worked at the Center for Ultrafast Optical Science; there were many different research projects over many years. The device used to make the movie in the TED talk is a streak camera; they were invented at least 50 years ago. My research was mostly laser-matter interactiom. See the link in my profile.

Comment: @Peter-Diehr thanks for the information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***Its really hard to do something like this but people at MIT have done something that might interest you.***

```
           (This is "not" a direct observation of light in slow motion)
```

They call it "**Femto-Photography**". The equipment they made captures images at a rate of roughly a **trillion frames per second**. But since direct recording of light is impossible at that speed, so the camera takes millions of **repeated scans** to recreate each image.

Below are some example time lapse images they have produced:

[image]  [image]

Please check out their website and read the Frequently Asked Questions on the page to get more understanding of this concept : [Femto-Photography: Visualizing Photons in Motion at a 
Trillion Frames Per Second](http://web.media.mit.edu/~raskar/trillionfps/)

Comment: light in slow motion looks diffused :)

Comment: @AnupamRekha yes I see that too :D

Comment: The image reconstruction techniques are responsible for some of the blurring; local air cuurents and temperature fluctuations for more; and vibrations of the optical table; there are similar limitations with holography.

Answer (score 1):

Things you have read about the scientists who are working to *slow down the light* is correct. But, a back-of-envelope calculation would show (utilizing *Heisenberg Uncertainty Principle*) that we will *never* be able to *see* both the *momentum* AND *position* (or in other words both the *energy* and *time duration* of a single photon) with infinite precisions; there is a lower limit in the product of their *observed* dispersions and this limit *cannot* be overcome in Nature. However, this only means that we need very high-tech instrumentations to be able to resolve those two *observables* in a statistical way. This is a very hard experiment to operate but I don't see it impossible. And I hope some experimentalist would help us to clarify the issue. So, the answer is, "It is possible, but experimentally challenging."